# Custom data attributes, chopped and embed a <img>

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have this in a mysql

```
<select>
<?php echo "<option value=\"\">Select Person:</option>";?>
<?php while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
echo "<option value='{$row['idvisa']}' data-visanumber='{$row['visanumber']}' data-idnumber='{$row['idnumber']}' data-statusapp='{$row['statusapp']}' data-accntVisaPhotoPath='{$row['accntVisaPhotoPath']}' data-passport='{$row['passportPath]}' data-subdate='{$row['subdate']}'>".$row['fName']." ".$row['lName']."</option>";

    }
?>
</select>
```

but then something got chopped.  It displays as "For" but when I checked it, it is supposedly "For Select" ..

And the script:

```
 <script>
$(function(){
    $('select').change(function(){
    var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
    var $parent = $(this).parents("tr");
    $parent.find('#visanumber').html(selected.data('visanumber')); 
    $parent.find('#idnumber').html(selected.data('idnumber')); 
    $parent.find('#statusapp').html(selected.data('statusapp')); 
    $parent.find('#accntVisaPhotoPath').html(selected.data('ImageUrl').accntVisaPhotoPath); //for testing
    $parent.find('#passportPath').html(selected.data('passportPath')); 
    });
 });
  </script>
```

My script is providing drop down dynamically but wonder why it is chopped.  And the second, how to embed an  tag in a custom data attributes?

And my [L A B](http://www.lab.workforceint.com/contract.php) ... It's almost 1 week already, please help. I have uprooted my hair, almost gone now.. lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you forgot quotes! Look into generated source code:

`<option value=1 data-visanumber=1234567890 data-idnumber=0987654321 data-statusapp=For Selection data-accntVisaPhotoPath= data-passport= data-subdate=2014-09-21 02:13:50>`

should be

`<option value="1" data-visanumber="1234567890" data-idnumber="0987654321" data-statusapp="For Selection" data-accntVisaPhotoPath="" data-passport="" data-subdate="2014-09-21 02:13:50">`

Comment: I have edited my .$row['statusapp']. into '{$row['statusapp']}', that fix my problem on chopping off.

Comment: Yes, as long as no statusapp contains apostrophe. Then you would need to prepare these data with htmlentities() function

Comment: By now, one still remains, the </img></img> thingy - embedding the custom data attributes.  With the htmlentities, Yes, but that is my last priority as of now.